# Файлы проекта не пушатся в репозиторий на GitHub

Tags: git, phpstorm, git-push

Создаю репозиторий на *GitHub* через *phpStorm*. Все отлично до момента *Commit and push* файлов. *Commit* проходит нормально, а вот *Push* повисает в процессе *phpStorm* и не загружается на *GitHub*.

Думал дело в фаерволе, но нет, и без него такая же ерунда. Подскажите, куда копать?

Comment: попробуйте сделать `git push` из каталога проекта (признак — в этом каталоге должен быть каталог `.git` c собственно репозиторием).

Comment: я как бы это и делаю, в phpStorm идет процесс pushing... и все...
Или вы имели ввиду как-то не через phpStorm?

Comment: я говорю про команду в консоли, а не про «обёртку» *phpstorm*.

Comment: пишет: git не является внешней или внутренней командой...

Comment: *ms/windows*? в этой системе, кажется, надо полный путь к программе `git` указывать ввиду того, что в переменную окружения PATH он не записывается.

Comment: в phpStorm я указал полный путь до git.exe (%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\bin)

Comment: попробуйте и в консоли его указать.

Comment: получилось через Git Shell, командой git push --set-upstream origin master, но в phpStorm по прежнему глухо, цель то именно через него настроить отправку.

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил запуск *phpStorm* с правами администратора. На Windows 10 такая фигня...

Comment: Как ужасна и бессмысленна Windows. )